# Nuxt CSS properties declared on :root selector are not found

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt 2 app and I'd like to create a component with a `<style>` tag like the following, using CSS properties for styling.

The goal is to define a default CSS property in the component that can be overridden from outside.

However, when I try this method, the default values don't seem to work at all.

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
:root {
  --default-badge-color: linear-gradient(90deg, #1717ff 0%, #bc29e0 92%);
  --default-badge-text-color: #fff;
  --default-badge-font-size: 1.6rem;
  --default-badge-padding: 0.6rem 1rem;
  --default-badge-border-radius: 16px;
}

.badge {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: var(--badge-padding, var(--default-badge-padding));
  border-radius: var(--badge-border-radius, var(--default-badge-border-radius));
  background: var(--badge-color, var(--default-badge-color));
  color: var(--badge-text-color, var(--default-badge-text-color));
  font-size: var(--badge-font-size, var(--default-badge-font-size));
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Do I have the wrong approach for the syntax?

**EDIT:** I corrected to `padding: var(--badge-padding, var(--default-badge-padding))`. But the CSS properties are still not found except I define them inside `.badge`.

Comment: `scoped` would break it as :root wont apply, work around it by setting the default when you set `badge-padding` vars etc, defaults don't need to go in :root

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I'm not sure I understood your answer correctly. The goal of this is to have a default style for the component, not to have to give the default everytime using `--badge-padding`-like vars. Where would you put for instance `--default-badge-padding`? Inside the `.badge` selector?

Comment: `document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--badge-padding', document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue('--badge-padding') || '0.6rem 1rem')` etc

Comment: or remove `scoped`

Comment: https://vuedose.tips/theming-using-custom-properties-in-vuejs-components

Comment: I followed this blog post, it seems to be working for them right? Even with `scoped`

Comment: @ThéoLavaux That post states: `We would normally define custom properties in another file and target the :root selector and not inside the component, but for the sake of this example we are going to do it inside the component.`. I think the author *assumed* `:root` would work in `<style scoped>`, but not sure. I don't see a demo there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to scope [`:root`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root), which is intended to select the *root of the document* with higher specificity than the `html` selector. That would be like scoping a style for `<body>`.

Perhaps you're hoping `:root` was a selector for the current component's root element (like [`:host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host_function) is for Shadow DOM), but there's no such pseudo-class in Vue. An alternative is to apply your own class to the component's root element, and use that as a selector:

```html
<template>      
  <div class="my-root">
    <div>...</div>
    <div class="badge">...</div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
   
.my-root {
   /* CSS custom properties */
}

.badge {
  /* styles using the CSS custom properties above */
}
</style>
```

On the other hand, if you really are trying to add CSS custom properties to the document root from within `<style scoped>`, you can use the [`:global()`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#scoped-css) pseudo-class function on `:root`:

```html
<style scoped>
:global(:root) {
  /* CSS custom properties */
}

.badge {
  /* styles using the CSS custom properties above */
}
</style>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-set-root-styles-from-style-scoped?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyBadge.vue)

Or a separate [global `<style>` block](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#scoped-css) just for `:root`:

```html
<style>
:root {
  /* CSS custom properties */
}
</style>

<style scoped>
.badge {
  /* styles using the CSS custom properties above */
}
</style>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-set-root-styles-from-style?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyBadge.vue)

Comment: My bad, you're totally right, I mixed the usages of `:host` and `:root` from what I remembered about making web components!